# PHP preg_split add split for new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm using this `preg_split` to split a pharagraph wherever there are dots that have a space or an uppercase alphabetical character after it:

```
$p = "This is a dummy text. And it has a new line in it \n it also has dots. Byt not";
$arr  = preg_split('/\.\s*?(?=[A-Z])/', $p);
```

This also prevents the last dot in a paragraph to be splitted(which is what i want) but, i now need it to split new lines(or rows) also. I can't manage to wrap my head around it... :(

Comment: `(\r\n|\n|\r)` if i remember correctly for new lines

Comment: hei @tim, i need to integrate it in my current pattern :(

Comment: so .. copy and paste

Comment: hey @Thefourthbird, i don't need it to split the last `.` i need it to split those dots that are inside the paragraph and also by that `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$arr  = preg_split('/\.\s*?(?=[A-Z])|(\r\n|\n|\r)/', $p);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you @Peter, it works perfectly! :D Thank you!:D

Answer (score 1):

You could split by using an alternation that matches either a dot followed by 0+ horizonal whitespace characters and then 1+ uppercase characters or `|` a unicode newline sequence:

```
\.(?=\h*[A-Z])|\R+
```

For example:

```
$p = "This is a dummy text. And it has a new line in it \n it also has dots. Byt not.";
$arr  = preg_split('/\.(?=\h*[A-Z])|\R+/', $p);
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCUxNo/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/cnmb8)

Comment: oh, thank you @Thefourthbird, i will use this one then :D but i've already checked a prefered answer :(

Comment: No problem at all! Good luck!

Comment: Hey one quick question, i have a problem that i just noticed(it is a problem that i have with my old pattern also), the dots dissapear, except the one at the end. Is there a way to keep the dots where they are? Thank you :D

Comment: noooo, i mean like this `[0] => This is a dummy text.` (the dot at the end of the string in the same array key - basically to split AFTER that dot i guess?)

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees! :D Thank youuuuuu thank you thank you! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185203/discussion-between-emma-and-the-fourth-bird).